# PHP: Require() and Class Hierarchies

Tags: php, oop, class-design, require

I'm considering this issue largely a C++/C# programmer, which might help put things into perspective. I haven't been able to find a simple answer to my question, so I apologize if there's one readily available out there. This seems like it'd be a very common issue.

Suppose I have **class A**, which is a container for instances of **class B**. **class B**, in turn, is a container for instances of **class C**. By container, I mean each class holds an array of certain kinds of objects and a few general parameters describing those objects. Each class is stored in [className].php

Now, I have a script that needs to build an instance of class A. In order to do so, it will need to construct instances of class C. Each set of those will be used to build an instance of class B, and finally, all of the class Bs will be used to build an instance of class A.

The question is, in PHP, where is the best (least-error prone) place to put the require() statements? Some ideas:

- require() all three classes in the script, and nowhere else
- require_once() the classes everywhere you need to use them. In this case, you'd require_once() A, B, and C in the script, require B and C in A, and require_once() C in B.
- require() only the class the next level down in the hierarchy. The script will require(A), A will require(B), and B will require(C). Thus, by requiring A in the script, you get access to all of the classes needed to populate A.
- Something else, like autoloading.

As always, I appreciate the ideas. While this might be subjective on some level, I do believe some ways may be objectively better than others, and that's what I'm after.

Comment: don't over-complicate the matter. use autoloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with autoloading. You don't have to worry about where you `require_once()` your classes if it does it automatically for you. All you have to do is start using the classes you expect to be there, and PHP will call your autoloader to make sure that the classes are loaded.

If you are more used to programming in an environment that has you import things at the top of each file, you might be more comfortable using `require_once()` at the top of all of your files. I almost prefer this over autoloading because it makes it very clear what each classes dependencies are. However, you get a lot of duplication which you might not enjoy.

Either way works. It is mostly a style choice.

Comment: If you use autoloading in this situation, where do you put the autoload function? In every executable php file?

Comment: Basically yes, though in reality you'd just require a file with the __autoload() in any "executable" code. Also checkout spl_register_autoload() - which will offer your more flexibility (although potentially against slightly reduced performance).

Comment: Doesn't `use` statements on top of the file describe class dependencies good enough?

Comment: I've chosen to simply require_once() any dependencies for now, as I like to readily see what I'm using and it makes the code clearer to others. However, for a larger program with a lot more files, or a situation where I have very high concurrency, I might consider using autoloading instead,

Answer (score 2):

Always use `require_once` to include classes. *Always*. There is literally no downside. Include the files via `require_once` in each file they're needed. This cannot fail: You cannot use `require_once` too many times, and the class is guaranteed to be included and available throughout the entire program.

Comment: +1 But only require the classes that you *actually use* in the source file.

Comment: Actually, there is a potential downside and that is (slightly) reduced performance. Read more here: http://www.techyouruniverse.com/software/php-performance-tip-require-versus-require_once .

Comment: @MathieuK Trying to optimize PHP is pointless. PHP-based optimization is rendered completely moot by output caching.

Comment: I disagree, there are plenty of situations thinkable where output caching simply isn't an option.