# Require inside classes = bad practice?

Tags: php, require

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Require() and Class Hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222124/php-require-and-class-hierarchies)

Is this bad practice?

Is there any actual difference between including them outside vs inside?

Comment: It seems that the answer to this question may answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222124/php-require-and-class-hierarchies

Comment: yes and yes. think of the scope

Comment: i'll vote to reopen if you update the question clarifying which parts explained in http://php.net/include you need help with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no actual difference between including them outside or inside a class.

Usually, the first start-up scripts are included outside classes since no class is available yet. 
Later, with respect to the OOP design, you could create a class for managing the imports of other files (possible other PHP classes or templates) which has its benefits: you define a base path for all files so you can import easily what you need, increase security by invoking scripts only through your mechanism etc.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your applications design you should only include something within an autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

When your require them in a class function it is only available after that require, when you do it outside it is available from any part of your application. It's best IMO to include them  outside the class in one location, it makes it easier to find when you need to see if you actually included it.

Comment: ok, but this is not a problem if you use a spl autoload, right? If yes, then there's no disadvantage between the two methods, right?

Comment: @Alex: that's exactly the advantage of autoloading. You only require in the classes when they're needed. Helps to bring down the memory usage and makes coding easier, but impacts performance (how much? depends on many factors).

Comment: Most of the stuff I write is framework based so I don't even think about the autoloading aspect these day as the framework handles it for me, but yes.